# Sympy inverse_laplace_transform isn't working?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm having a big issue with the inverse laplace transform in sympy when I try to antitransform (s + 0.2)/(s*(s + 0.2) + 1).

The code I'm using:

```
from sympy import *
s = symbols('s')
t = symbols('t')
f = (s + 0.2)/(s*(s + 0.2) + 1)
inverse_laplace_transform(f,s,t)
```

That code breaks the program and I don't understand why, because with others functions the method doesn't crash down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is a problem with the mpmath, that is a module for arbitrary precision arithmetic, or with the integration of this module with sympy.

You can circumvent the bug by replacing 0.2 by a rational. Something like this worked for me:

```
from sympy import *
s = symbols('s')
t = symbols('t')
a  = Rational(1, 5)
f = (s + a)/(s*(s + a) + 1)
inverse_laplace_transform(f,s,t)
```

That returns:

```
sqrt(11)*(sin(3*sqrt(11)*t/10) + 3*sqrt(11)*cos(3*sqrt(11)*t/10))*exp(-t/10)*Heaviside(t)/33
```