# Error in Inverse Laplace Transform with Python

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to get an inverse laplace of the expression

e^(-sqrt(2s)x).

But when I try to solve it using Python, I got an error.

Python code:

```
from sympy import exp, Symbol
from sympy.integrals.transforms import inverse_laplace_transform as ilt
from sympy.abc import x,s,t

f=-((2*s)**0.5)*x
invf=ilt(exp(f),s,t)
display(invf)
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)



File /lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py:562, in _inflate_fox_h(g, a)
    551 r"""
    552 Let d denote the integrand in the definition of the G function ``g``.
    553 Consider the function H which is defined in the same way, but with
   (...)
    559 This function returns C, G.
    560 """
    561 if a < 0:
--> 562     return _inflate_fox_h(_flip_g(g), -a)
    563 p = S(a.p)
    564 q = S(a.q)

File /lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/integrals/meijerint.py:563, in _inflate_fox_h(g, a)
    561 if a < 0:
    562     return _inflate_fox_h(_flip_g(g), -a)
--> 563 p = S(a.p)
    564 q = S(a.q)
    565 # We use the substitution s->qs, i.e. inflate g by q. We are left with an
    566 # extra factor of Gamma(p*s), for which we use Gauss' multiplication
    567 # theorem.

AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'p'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sympy inverse\_laplace\_transform isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470693/sympy-inverse-laplace-transform-isnt-working)